# multidimensional array search PHP reading from file

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi In another post I learned how to read data from a text file into an array. After the script reads the text file here is the resulting array of data.

What I'm trying to do is simply return the 'key' or record number where a search string appears i.e.  if I pass the parameter 'muscle3' it should return '3' because it is the third 'row' in the table

Then I can easily extract the other columns with $arrayTable[$keyVal][2] and $arrayTable[$keyVal][3]

As you can see the pageName which is the search field is stored in $arrayTable[$keyVal][2] 
By getting the $keyValue from a search, i can then get the other pages.

i.e.  mygreatwebsite.com/?page=muscle3
it then fetches the data from the array and it

But when I run the script below it gives the following error message

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
$page=$_REQUEST['page'];

$keyVal = searchForId($page,$arrayTable);  // this is the value I want returned


function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
print_r ($val); print "<br><br>";           
if ($val === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;


here is the output from the above script

Array ( [0] => muscle1 [1] => arrayField [2] => description )

Array ( [0] => muscle2 [1] => arrayField2 [2] => description )

Array ( [0] => muscle3 [1] => arrayField3 [2] => description )
```

Can someone help me figure this one out? Thanks!

Someone asked how the array table is being defined: here it is

```
$i=0;
if (($handle = fopen($inputFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $arrayTable[$i] = $data; $i++;
    }
fclose($handle);
}
```

input file is a CSV file with the first row containing column headings and each subsequent row containing data
the first column is called 'pageName'
 What I'm seeking to do is 'search' for the 'pageName' and just return which record.
i.e. Muscle 1 is in record #1  muscle3 is is record #3

its a simple example - the CSV file is much more complex that this.

Comment: Where is `$arrayTable` declared ?

Comment: check it wit this `if(is_array($array))`

Comment: @alfasin In the first docblock in the question.

Comment: @Jon In this case the error wouldn't appear... when it's still declared there.

Comment: @bwoebi True, but even if it gets past that, the comparison inside the function won't work because `$val` will be an array itself, so `$val[0]` if checking for the page name.

Comment: The array is declared by reading values from a text file into it. I did a print_r to show you the output.

Comment: @Viktor and the output looks like it contains page-ids ?